# Automatically factor in price increases of 10% for every 100 items for bulk purchases

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, exponential-function

I have a problem that can be described like this:

- we have an apple vendor who sells a rare sort of apple
- In order to keep his apples desirable and rare he wants to limit the amount of apples in circulation (meaning the amount of apples he has sold)
- but he also wants to make some decent money on his apples if they are not very popular currently
- an apple takes 2 weeks to rot from the point of sale

In order to achieve this he develops the following scheme

- The apple vendor keeps careful track of how many apples he sold and when they were sold
- that way he knows how many apples have spoiled and how many edible ones are still in circulation (A is the amount of apples sold by the vendor that have not yet spoiled)
- The vendor sells the apple for a base price plus 10% for all 100 apples in circulation according to this formula:

$price=B*(1.1^{\frac{A}{100}})$

- This way the apples will remain affordable when they are not very popular but become pricey fast if theres a run on the market
- Meaning apple price should increase with the baseprice (B), increase with the amount of apples in circulation (A) (ie first apple costs 1\$, second costs $1.1^{\frac{1}{100}}$\$, third costs $(1.1^{\frac{1}{100}})^{2}$\$ and 101th costs $(1.1^{\frac{1}{100}})^{100}= 1.1)$\$, assuming apples would be sold one at a time

To clarify: as long as apples don't rot, and if they are sold apple by apple the apples prices form a simple curve of the form $price=baseprice*(1.1^\frac{totalApplesSold}{100})$

Now heres the problem: Most people want to buy more than one apple. But with this formula, the apple vendor has to sell an apple, recalculate the price, then sell an apple again. Is there a way that I can modify this formula, so that I can just plug in the amount of (unspoiled) apples that have been sold (A), the amount of apples a customer wants to buy and then get the price for all the apples, which have become more expensive with each apple?

I know one way to solve this would be to take the derivative of the function. But I'm not sure if this would work since we are talking about individual apples, which get progressively more expensive with each individual one instead of gradually so I'm unsure if derivatives fit here.

Another one would treating the whole process as a series and using a riemann zeta formula, but I don't know enough about those to definitively say that they are the solution here.

Comment: The formula does not make sense, one in any power is one.

Comment: Yeah i really messed that one up, one moment

Answer (score 0):

I think your formula for the price is still wrong. It should be $P=B\cdot 1.1^{\frac{A}{100}}$. If customer buys $n$ apples, the total price can be calculated as (using geometric series)$$Total=B\sum_{i=1}^n1.1^{\frac{A-i}{100}}=B\cdot 1.1^{\frac{A}{100}}\sum_{i=1}^n(1.1^{\frac{-1}{100}})^i=B\cdot 1.1^{\frac{A}{100}}\cdot \frac{1-1.1^{\frac{-n}{100}}}{1-1.1^{\frac{-1}{100}}}$$ Of course, you still need to adjust number $A$ after each sale.

Comment: B is the baseprice so I think it needs to be added, A is the total amount of apples sold

Comment: @user2741831 Increasing $B$ by $10\%$ is equivalent to multiplying $B$ by $1.1$

Comment: oh, you are right. I guess B could be a counted for by simply adding a constant amount of apples before the first purchase

Comment: thanks, I didn't have time to test your formula today, I'll do it tomorrow and mark your answer then

Comment: @user2741831: Exactly, $B+0.1B=1.1B$ so the base price is always there. It's important to get it right though, try to calculate price for 100, 200, etc and see if that's what you want

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/M2iXzhu.png https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1i8rd3mmox I set the Baseprice to 1, which should be equivalent to a baseprice of 1 and the amount of apples sold before purchase to 0. If I buy one apple, its correct but the price is reduced upon every subsequent apple, when it should increase (to 1+1.1=2.1). Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @user2741831: Because the amount of apples in circulation is decreasing when you sell apples, the surcharge is also decreasing. Perhaps you need to provide more examples for me to understand what formula you have in mind. Let's say there are 100 apples. What should be the price of the first one? Second? etc.

Comment: A can decrease if apples rot, but I don't think that matters for the formula, since the apples are sold all at once, meaning A is constant during the transaciton

Comment: Well the apples in circulation increase with each apple sold(I'm sorry if that was confusing I will adjust the post), just like when the fed prints money, the amount of money in circulation increases. The apples in circulation can only decrease when they rot. The very first apple sold (when there are none in circulation) would cost 1$ (assuming baseprice=1\$). The second one would cost sligtly more, 1.1^(1/100)\$, and the 101th apple would cost 1.1(100/100)= 1.1\$, since the price increase by 10% per hundred apples.

Comment: It really doesn't matter if the amount of apples increases through apples in the current transaction or if they were sold earlier. All I need is a formula that performs the price calculation for multiple apples in a single step instead of at an apple by apple basis